# Custom fields disappeared from new order email, Woocomerce

Tags: php, wordpress, woocommerce, email

I added some custom form fields by doing echo in functions.php,and followed some examples to setup custom form fields in email, but recently they stopped showing in emails although i am getting all those fields in order details in custom fields portion.

## Following is the functions.php code

## Fields echo code

```
    function self_added_checkout_fieldsPk1($fields)
      {
         echo '<div class="row" style="text-aign:center">
           <div class="col m4 offset-m4" align="center">
              <ul class="collapsible" data-collapsible="expandable">
                 <li class="">
                      <div class="collapsible-header active"><b>Instagram Account No.1 Details</b></div>
                     <div class="collapsible-body" style="display: none; padding-top: 0px; margin-top: 0px; padding-bottom: 0px; margin-bottom: 0px;">
                    <div class="input-field col s12">
                            Username: <input id="acc1user" name="acc1user" type="text" class="validate" required>
                            Password: <input id="acc1pass" name="acc1pass" type="text" class="validate" required>Account No.1 Audience: <input id="acc1audi" name="acc1audi" type="text" class="validate" required>
        Note: Your Login Credentials will be safe with us do not worry.
                    </div>
                    </div>
              </li>
                </ul>
            </div></div>
    </h1>';}

And similarly many more fields as above
#Order Meta Update code
    /**
     * Update the order meta with field value for Package 1
     */

    add_action( 'woocommerce_checkout_update_order_meta',   'my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta' );

    function my_custom_checkout_field_update_order_meta( $order_id ) {

    //Username and Password for 1st Account of Instagram

     if ( ! empty( $_POST['acc1user'] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $order_id, 'Username1', sanitize_text_field(     $_POST['acc1user'] ) );
        }

    if ( ! empty( $_POST['acc1pass'] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $order_id, 'Password1', sanitize_text_field(     $_POST['acc1pass'] ) );
        }

    if ( ! empty( $_POST['acc1audi'] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $order_id, 'Account No.1 Audience', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['acc1audi'] ) );
        }

        if ( ! empty( $_POST['acc2user'] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $order_id, 'Username2', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['acc2user'] ) );
        }

    if ( ! empty( $_POST['acc2pass'] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $order_id, 'Password2', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['acc2pass'] ) );
        }

    if ( ! empty( $_POST['acc2audi'] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $order_id, 'Account No.1]2 Audience', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['acc2audi'] ) );
        }

     if ( ! empty( $_POST['acc3user'] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $order_id, 'Username3', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['acc3user'] ) );
        }

    if ( ! empty( $_POST['acc3pass'] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $order_id, 'Password3', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['acc3pass'] ) );
        }

    if ( ! empty( $_POST['acc3audi'] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $order_id, 'Account No.3 Audience', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['acc3audi'] ) );
        }

    if ( ! empty( $_POST['acc4user'] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $order_id, 'Username4', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['acc4user'] ) );
      }

    if ( ! empty( $_POST['acc4pass'] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $order_id, 'Password4', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['acc4pass'] ) );
        }

    if ( ! empty( $_POST['acc4audi'] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $order_id, 'Account No.4 Audience', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['acc4audi'] ) );
        }
    
     if ( ! empty( $_POST['acc5user'] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $order_id, 'Username5', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['acc5user'] ) );
        }
    if ( ! empty( $_POST['acc5pass'] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $order_id, 'Password5', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['acc5pass'] ) );
        }

    if ( ! empty( $_POST['acc5audi'] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $order_id, 'Account No.5 Audience', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['acc5audi'] ) );
       }
    if ( ! empty( $_POST['acc6user'] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $order_id, 'Username6', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['acc6user'] ) );
        }
    if ( ! empty( $_POST['acc6pass'] ) ) {
        update_post_meta( $order_id, 'Password6', sanitize_text_field( $_POST['acc6pass'] ) );
        }
        }
```

including meta orders in email code

```
/**
* Email include "Metadata" on Order Emails
*
*/

    add_filter( 'woocommerce_email_order_meta_keys', 'xcsn_woocommerce_email_order_meta_keys' );

    function xcsn_woocommerce_email_order_meta_keys( $keys ) {
   
        global $post;
        $post_id = $post->ID;

    //For Package 1
       
        if ( !empty( $post_id )) {
       
            // Check the POST data is being submitted
            if ( $_POST['acc1user'] ) {
        
        $keys[] = 'acc1user';
               
                // Writes directly into the email body
                echo '<h2>Instagram Account No.1 Username</h2>';
               
                $my_test_field_output = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['acc1user']  );
                echo '<p>' . $my_test_field_output . '</p>';
            }

        if ( $_POST['acc1pass'] ) {

        $keys[] = 'acc1pass';
               
                // Writes directly into the email body
                echo '<h2>Instagram Account No.1 Password</h2>';
               
                $my_test_field_output = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['acc1pass'] );
                echo '<p>' . $my_test_field_output . '</p>';
            echo '</br>';
            }

    if ( $_POST['acc1audi'] ) {

        $keys[] = 'acc1audi';
               
                // Writes directly into the email body
                echo '<h2>Instagram Account No.1 Audience</h2>';
               
                $my_test_field_output = sanitize_text_field( $_POST['acc1audi'] );
                echo '<p>' . $my_test_field_output . '</p>';
            echo '</br>';
            }
           
          }     
        return $keys;
    }
```

Comment: Question is at top following is just code

Comment: You are mixing approaches.... the `woocommerce_email_order_meta` keys only expects you to return an array. You are also trying to echo things. Take a look at the email portion of my [tutorial on custom checkout fields](http://www.kathyisawesome.com/woocommerce-customize-checkout-fields/), specifically the last block.